# Subversion on macOS Catalina (10.15) producing very strange/incorrect behavior

Tags: command-line, catalina, homebrew, subversion

I've just moved to macOS Catalina 10.15, and installed Subversion via Homebrew. That appeared to go well; `svn --version` and `svn help` both work, and I was able to use `svn checkout` to check out a small repo.

But when I go down into that repo and do a `svn status`, the three files it just pulled down and are definitely there are marked with `!` (deleted) status, and there's this weird extra file with the gibberish name `H?\85?\C0?\84?\92`.

```
Password for 'jstrout': ***********

A    notes/PerformanceNotes.txt
A    notes/StateAndStorage.txt
A    notes/idealNetworkDesign.txt
Checked out revision 1370.
√ svnrepo % cd notes                                                                                                                                                                     
√ notes % dir                                                                                                                                                                            
total 24
drwxr-xr-x   6 jstrout  staff   192 Aug 31 16:32 .
drwxr-xr-x  13 jstrout  staff   416 Aug 31 16:32 ..
drwxr-xr-x   8 jstrout  staff   256 Aug 31 16:32 .svn
-rw-r--r--   1 jstrout  staff  2613 Aug 31 16:32 PerformanceNotes.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 jstrout  staff  1323 Aug 31 16:32 StateAndStorage.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 jstrout  staff  2384 Aug 31 16:32 idealNetworkDesign.txt
```

So far so good, everything it just brought down looks correct...

```
√ notes % svn st                                                                                                                                                                         
?       H?\85?\C0?\84?\92
!       PerformanceNotes.txt
!       StateAndStorage.txt
!       idealNetworkDesign.txt
```

What? I've never seen this sort of behavior from `svn` in my life. Any idea what could be wrong here?

Comment: What did you expect to see?

Comment: What does `which svn` show?